# Matrix SDK get list of messages

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, matrix

I'm trying to call to get API of [matrix client](https://matrix.org/docs/spec/r0.0.0/client_server#get-matrix-client-r0-rooms-roomid-messages) in order to get all the list of the messages from server.

```
let token = this.matrixClient.store.syncToken
      axios.get(`https://matrix.org/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/${this.roomId}/messages`, {from: token}).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

Response with 401 (network tab)

```
{errcode: "M_MISSING_TOKEN", error: "Missing access token"}
errcode: "M_MISSING_TOKEN"
error: "Missing access token"
```

Can anyone please elaborate with an example here